# How to get rid of "Using TensorFlow backend." in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter, warnings

When I run this code, this "Using TensorFlow backend" always pops up.

[image]

Even after I tried

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.simplefilter('ignore)
```

I wonder whether I can get rid of it to make my notebook look cleaner.

Comment: Keras requires tensorflow. Keras is like API over tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with tf-2.0 Keras is now the official high-level API of TensorFlow packaged within it. Not sure if it is a possibility in your case, but using tf-2.0 should remove this error. Here's a [Quick Start](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) guide if needed. 
For most of the simple cases, just changing the import statement to `import tensorflow.keras as keras` gets it going.